# Как в C# безопасно предать параметр SQL функции?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Вот код, которым у меня выходит получать таблицу

```
 public void GetEmployeeByLogin(string login)
 {
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetEmployeeByLogin('" + login + "')", conn))
         {
             comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
             conn.Open();
             using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     // Работа с данными
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Но строка `using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetEmployeeByLogin('" + login + "')", conn))` небезопасна для SQL-инъекций.

Каким образом можно получить возвращаемую из функции таблицу безопасно?

Comment: SQL-функции - это прекрасно, но где же функция C#, которой планируется выполнять этот запрос и получать результат? "Слова - ничто, покажите мне код" ©️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так, без склейки строк (что и делает возможной SQL injection):

```
     public void GetEmployeeByLogin(string login)
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
         conn.Open();    
         using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetEmployeeByLogin(@login)", conn))
             {
                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
                 comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                 using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         // Работа с данными
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Есть определенные возражения против использования AddWithValue(), но так явно будет лучше, чем было.

Comment: `comm.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = login;`